# MySQL Query - how to keep normal users from seeing staff posts?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

On my forum, I'm having an issue where non-staff members can view staff related posts that are otherwise hidden to normal users. Upon investigating I've discovered that staff related topics do not show up, whereas individual posts do.

In my `controller/profile.php`, for posts ([live sample](http://www.caedon.net/profile/view_posts/1/28)), it shows:

```
$user_posts = $this->db->query("SELECT topics.topic_id as tp_id,
                                forums.staff,
                                topics.topic_title,
                                tp_new.post_id as ps_id,
                                tp_new.topic_post_id as tps_id,
                                tp_new.topic_id,
                                tp_new.author_id,
                                tp_new.post_time,
                                topic_post_text.text as post_body
                        FROM (SELECT post_id FROM topic_posts WHERE topic_posts.author_id = ".$user_id." ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT ".$this->uri->segment(4, 0).", ".$config['per_page'].") tp_old
                        JOIN topic_posts tp_new ON tp_new.post_id = tp_old.post_id
                        JOIN `topic_post_text` ON `topic_post_text`.`post_id` = `tp_new`.`post_id`
                        JOIN `topics` ON `tp_new`.`topic_id` = `topics`.`topic_id`
                        JOIN `forums` ON `forums`.`forum_id` = `topics`.`forum_id`
                        ORDER BY tp_new.post_id DESC")->result_array();
```

And for topics ([live sample](http://www.caedon.net/profile/view_topics/1)), it shows:

```
    $user_topics = $this->db->select('*')
                            ->from('topics')
                            ->where('topics.topic_author', $user_id)
                            ->where('forums.staff', 0)
                            ->join('forums', 'forums.forum_id = topics.forum_id')
                            ->order_by('topics.topic_id', 'desc')
                            ->limit($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4, 0))
                            ->get()
                            ->result_array();
```

How do I change my posts display to not show staff posts?

Comment: Sorry for not actually contributing an answer, but the code looks a [little scary to me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). At the very least, I tried the URL http://www.caedon.net/profile/view_posts/1/hello and all of the SQL code was revealed. Make sure the wrong people aren't looking at it ;)

Comment: where are your levels to differentiate who is a staff user and who is normal user?

Comment: @RowanFreeman How do I get it to see an alternative? :x

Comment: @Bender I think 0 = staff?